# Haskell - Non-exhaustive patterns in function using data type

Tags: haskell, recursion, types

I was trying to solve this question on Haskell wiki: https://wiki.haskell.org/99_questions/11_to_20 (problem 12)

My solution is as follows:

```
data Repeats a = Single a | Multiple Int a deriving Show

encodelens :: Eq a => [a] -> [Repeats a]
encodelens xs = foldr (\x acc -> case acc of
                                  [] -> [Single x]
                                  (l:ls) -> case l of
                                             (Single x') -> if x == x'
                                                             then [(Multiple 2 x)] ++ ls
                                                             else [(Single x)] ++ (l:ls)
                                             (Multiple c x') -> if x == x'
                                                                 then [(Multiple (c+1) x)] ++ ls
                                                                 else [(Single x)] ++ (l:ls)
                      ) [] xs

decodelens :: Eq a => [Repeats a] -> [a]
decodelens [] = []
deocdelens (r:rs) = case r of
                     (Single x) -> [x] ++ decodelens rs
                     (Multiple c x) -> take c (repeat x) ++ decodelens rs
```

`decodelens` does not work, it fails with:

```
decodelens [Multiple 4 'a',Multiple 2 'b',Multiple 2 'c',Multiple 2 'd',Single 'e',Multiple 3 'f']

"*** Exception: encode-len-with-cardinality.hs:(17,1)-(19,47): Non-exhaustive patterns in function decodelens
```

I am not sure how it is unable to pattern match.

*Update*:

As pointed out in comments below, the mistake is in the function name for the second pattern match `deocdelens`. *I wonder is there is a way to avoid such mistakes?*

Comment: Look at the spelling of the function name: deocde vs. decode.

Comment: damn, such a simple mistake. Is there anyway to avoid such mistakes?

Comment: We all make mistakes like that, this is why ghc is a great pair programming partner.

Comment: @Ngm Yes, there is a way -- turn on warnings with `-Wall`! GHC should warn you about 1) the non-exhaustive match and 2) a function `deocde` begin defined without a type annotation `deocde :: ...`. The second one should point out the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is indeed a difficult type of error to catch. Notice that if you had a typo on either the signature or the first pattern for `decodelens`, GHC would have complained because the signature must be "adjacent" to the function definition.

I think the best you can do here is turn on `-Wmissing-signatures`. For the code above, this will trigger a warning about the top-level function `deocdelens` not having a signature. Of course this means you have to explicitly write signatures for all top-level functions, but this is generally encouraged anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of Haskell vs other languages, one thing that does prevent this kind of problem is to make it a habit *never to type out* names with more than three letters (except when writing it the first time, usually for the signature). That's what autocompletion is there for.

Of course this has its own problems – I have more than once found myself typing a name wrong *the first time* and then autocomplete-“pasting” it across my program. Which will then work just fine, it's just a bit embarrassing when reading the code...